# SASS: how to use cross-file extension?

Tags: sass

I have couple of sass files:

- `_common.sass` - everything that is used globally, including variables, mixins etc.
- `partials/_partial.sass` - partial styles
- `homepage.sass` - homepage specific

Now the problem:

If I import `_common.sass` into the `partial/_partial.sass` and then import `partials/_partial.sass` into the `homepage.sass`, well, `_common.sass` gets compiled twice. Bad.

The whole point is that the `homepage.sass` has to reference the `_common.sass`, so it could extend global class definitions and use mixins and os on, as well as the `_partial.sass` has to have access to global things from `_common.sass`. But `_partial.sass` itself has to be imported into the `homepage.sass`.

Sounds something very simple and unworthy, but Im having hard times solving that puzzle.

## Edit (to clear things out):

```
// _common.sass
.sprite
    background: url(sprite.png)

// _partial.sass
@import "common"
.link
    @extend .sprite

// homepage.sass
@import "common"
.social
   @extend .sprite
@import "partials/partial"
```

As you can see that both homepage and partial extend global class `.sprite`. This is what I'm trying to achieve. But in the end, homepage gets the whole content of `_common.sass` compiled per nested import (2 times, in particular example)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you're asking... but won't it work to simply put `@import "common"` and `@import "partials/partial"` at the top of your `homepage.sass` file?

Comment: Sorry for making it unclear. I'll add additional info.

Comment: Done editing. But you've pointed out one keyword there `at the top`. I will try it out.

Comment: Just checked. Same result. `common` gets compiled 2 times.

Comment: Hm. So your problem is that `common` gets compiled twice, even if there is only one `@import` reference to `common` (e.g. `partial` imports `common` and `homepage` imports `partial` but not `common`)?

Comment: Quite opposite, `homepage` imports `common` and `partial`, while `partial` imports only `common`. However, I figured it out — yes, you are absolutely right. If `homepage` imports `common` and `partial`, while `partial` imports nothing at all - it works. Thank you for help. I knew it was something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Layout of a 'master' SASS file

The way I normally do this is include the file at the start of my `site.scss` file.

**site.scss**

```css
// variables, mixins, etc. at beginning
@import "common/_variables"
@import "common/_mixins"
@import "common/_sizes"
// ...

// your styles that use the variables, mixins, etc.
@import "modules/_blah"
// ...
```

Note that if the file contains only mixins, variables etc. then it is OK to include it multiple times as no output would result. For some text editors/IDEs you will need to do this for intellisense to kick in.

#### The _filename standard

SASS has a standard naming convention that a file that begins with an underscore `_` isn't meant to be compiled, only used as a partial file for other files. Using this naming convention may stop compilation errors depending on what tools you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the following: simply create a file that will add _common.scss initially.

```
// index.scss
@import "common"
@import "homepage"
   // inside homepage
   @import "partials/partial";
```

If you do so, I think that the things in common will be available for homepage and for partial, because they are imported above them. I.e. you don't need to import common inside homepage or partial.